# Access a protected Objective-C ivar from Swift subclass / extension

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Objective-C, I'm able to access `@protected` ivars in subclasses:

Interface Declaration:

```c
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
@protected
    NSString* _protectedString;
}
@end
```

Subclass Implementation:

```c
@implementation OtherClass : SomeClass
- (void)someFunc
{
    self->_protectedString; // OK
}
@end
```

Is there a way to do the same thing in a Swift subclass and / or extension? I've tried both `extension SomeClass` and `class SomeClassChild: SomeClass` and I get the same result:

```swift
extension SomeClass {
    func extensionFunc() {
        self._protectedString // compiler error: "Value of type SomeClass has no member '_protectedString'"
    }
}
```

Searching for this mainly gives me articles on "Swift Access Control", so I'm hoping someone has a bit better knowledge of Swift <=> Obj-C interop than I do.

Comment: For now I've opted for KVC functions (`self.value(forKey: "_protectedString")` / `self.setValue(value, forKey: "_protectedString")`, but I'd really like to know if there's a non-runtime-manipulation way to do it.